GTK3 Could not find signal handler with CMake, Glade & CLion
When i try to run GTK3 with Clion, CMake & Glade with the below config i get the following warning:
 Could not find signal handler 'on_dumpButton_clicked'.  Did you compile with -rdynamic?

So GTK cannot find any of my signal handlers.
CMAKE setup:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)
project(pg_backer C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)

file(COPY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/glade" DESTINATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})

find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(GTK3 REQUIRED gtk+-3.0)
include_directories(${GTK3_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${GTK3_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${GTK3_CFLAGS_OTHER})

add_executable(pg_backer main.c)
target_link_libraries(pg_backer PUBLIC
        ${GTK3_LIBRARIES}
)


I expected the Glade builder to link my signal handlers but the warning states that GTK could not find them even though they are declared in my code and glade file.

Update you CmakeLists.txt file with the -export-dynamic flag
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-Wl,-export-dynamic")

Your CMake file should now look like this:
project(pg_backer C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)

set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-Wl,-export-dynamic") # <----- here

file(COPY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/glade" DESTINATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})

find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(GTK3 REQUIRED gtk+-3.0)
include_directories(${GTK3_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${GTK3_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${GTK3_CFLAGS_OTHER})

add_executable(pg_backer main.c)
target_link_libraries(pg_backer PUBLIC
        ${GTK3_LIBRARIES}
)


Sample C code that links a few widgets & uses the builder to get the glade file and return it as a GTK object:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

GtkWidget       *mainWindow;
GtkWidget       *mainWindowFixedContainer;
GtkWidget       *dumpButton;
GtkWidget       *dumpLabel;
GtkBuilder      *builder;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("Loading PG Backer...\n");
    // Init GTK
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
    // Glade setup
    builder = gtk_builder_new_from_file("glade/pg_backer.glade");
    // build gtk widgets
    mainWindow = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "mainWindow"));
    mainWindowFixedContainer = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "mainWindowFixedContainer"));
    dumpButton = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "dumpButton"));
    dumpLabel = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "dumpLabel"));
    // window
    g_signal_connect(mainWindow, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
    // signals
    gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder, NULL);

    gtk_widget_show(mainWindow);
    // Run app
    gtk_main();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void on_dumpButton_clicked(GtkButton  *b)
{
    gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(dumpLabel), (const gchar*)"Are you sure you want to dump X db from host?");
}

